# user authentication by email and password from database in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

i am a beginner in django. I am working on a project in which customer and companies have their own accounts the models.py is:

```
class Company_SignUp(models.Model):
   comp_name = models.CharField(_('Company Name'), max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField(_('E-mail'), unique=True)
   raise forms.ValidationError("This email address already exists.")
   password1 = models.CharField(_('Password'), max_length=128)
   password2 = models.CharField(_('Confirm Password'), max_length=30)

   def __unicode__(self):
       return smart_unicode(self.comp_name)

class Customer_SignUp(models.Model):
   cust_name = models.CharField(_('Customer Name'), max_length=30)
   email = models.EmailField(_('E-mail'), unique=True)
   password1 = models.CharField(_('Password'), max_length=128)
   password2 = models.CharField(_('Confirm Password'), max_length=30) 

   def __unicode__(self):
       return smart_unicode(self.cust_name)
```

my forms.py is:

```
class Company(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company_SignUp
        widgets = {
          'password1': forms.PasswordInput(),
          'password2': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
        fields = ('email','password1','password2','comp_name')

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in       self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
            elif len(self.cleaned_data['password1']) < 8:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password must be 8 characters long."))

        return self.cleaned_data

class Customer(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer_SignUp
        widgets = {
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'password2': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }  
    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
            elif len(self.cleaned_data['password1']) < 8:
              raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password must be 8 characters long."))

        return self.cleaned_data
```

how will i authenticate a company or a customer using their email and passwords.
i tried authenticate() but it doesn't work. 
also how will i check during registration , the email address given already exists

ok now i created a backend which is:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from prmanager.models import Company_SignUp, Customer_SignUp

```
class EmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            o = Company_SignUp.objects.get(email=username, password1=password)
        except Company_SignUp.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                o = Customer_SignUp.objects.get(email=username, password1=password)
            except Customer_SignUp.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        return User.objects.get(email=o.email)
   def get_user(self, user_id):
       try:
          return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
       except User.DoesNotExist:
           return None
```

But now i cannot login to admin page using superuser credentials. what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Models**

Consider extending the `User` model from `django.contrib.auth.models` like so. If you don't want to do this, skip to the next section (Authentication).

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(User):
    # extra fields
```

The `User` model has common fields such as `username`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`, etc. You only need to specify any extra attributes your model may have.

The Django docs suggest extending `AbstractBaseUser`, which may work for you too.

Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

**Authentication**

For email-based authentication, you need to write your own authentication backend: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Once you have that in place, you need to accept email / password and authenticate using `authenticate` and `login`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def my_view(request):
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
    else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
```

The above snippet is from the docs and I have modified it to fit your use-case.

More about authentication in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in